# VBScript: Retrieving value from inside an object property

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to retrieve automatically generated information from the Notes field of an AD group and get a specific value out of it. I'm able to find the group I need and pull out the data using Get("Info"), but I'm stuck on how to get what I need out of it. Here's an example of what I'll be seeing:

```
Value1=True
Value2=name@domain.org
Value3=Something Else
```

What I need to do is find Value2 and put it into a variable. I've done this out of text files before, but this seems to work a bit differently and I'm stumped.

edit: to be clear, here's basic code:

```
Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://cn=Group Name,ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=org")
wscript.echo objGroup.Get("Info")
```

That would return the above example. I need to find "Value2" from that and put just its value (in this case, "name@domain.org") into a new variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
For Each v In Split(objGroup.Get("Info"), vbNewLine)
  If LCase(Left(v, 6)) = "value2" Then
    a = Split(v, "=", 2)
    If UBound(a) = 1 Then var = Trim(a(1))
  End If
Next
```

Comment: I like the direction this is going, but something isn't quite working with it. I'm running with it to see if I find a solution.

Comment: I might be able to assist with that if you can explain in more detail how exactly "something isn't quite working with it".

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a value to a variable as simply as:

```
Value3 = Get("info")
```

Comment: That's not at all what I'm trying to do.